# How to make a scrolling level with the 'with open('map.txt','r') as m' where map.txt contains the tiles of the level?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I would like to make a very big scrolling map for a pygame game.
My screen is define by 17x11 tiles of 120 px X 120 px ( tile in border are cut, 60px by 6)px for low resolution mod ). For create my scrolling, I've got the idea to use the 'with open('map.txt','r') as m' for avoid a load of a very large picture that make crash my program.
Let's suppose I got this in my file ( 1 = a wall and 0 = air ) :

```
111111111101111111111
100000000000000000001
101000000000000000101
100000000000000000001
100000000000000000001
100000000000000000001
100000000000000000001
100000000000000000001
101000000000000000101
100000000000000000001
111111111111111111111
```

the player appear in ( 9, 5 ), the top left is ( 0, 0 ).
So, I would like when my player go up, left, down, or right, the background reload for update is position on the map. Or,... I don't knwo how I can do this at all...

I've try this little script but is not work at all :

```
import pygame, os
pygame.init()
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
w = pygame.display.set_mode(1920,1080),pygame.NOFRAME)

wall = pygame.image.load('wall.png').convert_alpha
player = pygame.image.load('hero.png').convert_alpha

p_x = 9
p_y = 5
continue = True

def scroll(x,y):
     p_x = p_x + x
     p_y = p_y + y
     with open('map.txt','r') as m:
          **On your answer, complete this part  for aloow the code to work properly**
     pygame.display.update()

while continue:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == K_d: # I use a Qwerty keyboard
              scroll(1,0)
         elif event.type == K_a:
              scroll(-1,0)
         elif event.type == K_z:
              scroll(0,-1)
         elif event.type == K_s:
              scroll(0,1)
```

So I've already try the :

```
for line in m():
     for sprite in line():
          ....
```

And I think it's impossible with this method. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can't call a variable `continue`. It is a keyword. And `While` should be `while`.

Comment: I set continue = True

Comment: Yes, `continue = True` is a syntax error.

Comment: `continue  = True` and `while continue:` work for me wihout any problem... If you got problem with this, consider it as a `continue = 1` and `while continue == 1:`

Comment: A map that small can absolutely be loaded into memory without having to go through any hoops here.

Comment: @AKX I said Let's suppose, so, in real the map is really really more big but I cant's copy there else It will show just a tone of zero, 1, 2, 3,...

Comment: If we assume it's 1000 x 1000, you're still looking at only 8 megabytes of memory consumption. `sys.getsizeof([0] * 1000 * 1000)` prints out `8,000,064`.

Comment: You should avoid doing any file I/O in the main animation loop.

Comment: Suggest you make the scrolling map and image? Seems wasteful to effectively have two representations of it...

Comment: @AkX but in this case, it's not 1000x 1000 but it's (1000 x 120)²

Comment: @Edhyjox What do you mean with the ² there?

Comment: @AKX for the continue = True, I find the problem : conitnue make a syntax error cause continue is a elemnt of python, I've use Continue and not continue, cause I thought that will change nothing to remove the upper case

Comment: Python is case-sensitive; `Continue` and `continue` are two completely separate tokens.

Comment: Yeah, for this one, the error come from me

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon the discussion in comments:

Unless your map is really really *really* **really** **really** huge, I wouldn't bother with a system like this (although of course it's possible to implement).

Assuming your map is 1000 x 1000 integers, we can see that it would take about 8 megabytes of memory (on my Python). (Commas added to output for readability.)

```py
>>> sys.getsizeof([0] * 1000 * 1000)
8,000,064
```

If we expand to, oh, say, 5000 x 5000 integers (so given your screen size of 1920x1080 px and tile size of 60x60 px, 156 x 278 screenfuls!), we're still not looking at an impossible amount of memory (namely 200 megabytes):

```py
>>> sys.getsizeof([0] * 5000 * 5000)
200,000,064
```

Comment: Hey @Akx, you forgot to think about any tiles taht make 60px by 60px and 120 by 120 for full resolution ! So, cause it's a square for a simple 1000 tile by 1000 tiles we got this :  (1000x120)x(1000x120). This is why the picture can't be loaded by pygame : it's too big ! So it's make 41198.73046875 Mega bytes ( from File size calculator) ...

Comment: No – each tile image itself will (should!) be stored in memory only once, but drawn multiple times.

Comment: That I want to make with the file map

Comment: Am I to understand that each tile in your map has a different graphic?

Comment: yeah, there is different graphics like : w1  to w8 = wall type 1 to 8, c = chest, d = door,...

Comment: Yes, but those are still not unique graphics per-tile. You'd have 10 or 20 different bitmaps you'd draw on screen according to the map, so no need to hold anything but the contents of the screen in memory graphics-wise.

Comment: Not at hand, unfortunately, but the idea is pretty general.

Comment: I'm sceaching a working solution, so until you say me one, I will continue to thinking about this last... I don't really see what is your idea exactly